# Create an Order automatically when a new product is added to wishlist of customer

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, wishlist

When a new product is added in Magento catalog, it should get added to the wishlist of the customer and an order should be automatically created for it. I am using the following code. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<?php

namespace Wishorder\Asorder\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Wishorder\Asorder\Helper\Data;
class Cwish extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_wishlistRepository;
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $WishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Custom\Wlist\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []       
    ) {
        $this->_wishlistFactory= $WishlistFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHelloWorldTxt(){
        return 'Hello world!';
    }


    public function getProductCollection() 
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $cust) 
        { 
            $Email=$cust->getEmail(); 
            echo "Email : ".$Email.'<br/>';

            $Fname=$cust->getFirstname();
            $Lname=$cust->getLastname();
            echo "First Name : ".$Fname.'<br/>';
            echo "Last Name : ".$Lname.'<br/>';

            $CustomerModel->loadByEmail($Email);
            $userId = $CustomerModel->getId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $wishlist = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
            $wishlist_collection = $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($userId, true)->getItemCollection();
            echo "Last Name : ".$userId.'<br/>';
            print_r($wishlist_collection); die;

            foreach ($wishlist_collection as $wlist)
            {
                $orderData=[
                    'currency_id'  => 'USD',
                    'email'        => $Email, //buyer email id
                    'shipping_address' =>[
                    'firstname'    => $Fname, //address Details
                    'lastname'     => $Lname,
                    'street' => 'xxxxx',
                    'city' => 'xxxxx',
                    'country_id' => 'IN',
                    'region' => 'xxx',
                    'postcode' => '43244',
                    'telephone' => '52332',
                    'fax' => '32423',
                    'save_in_address_book' => 1],
                    'items'=> ['product_id'=>$wlist->getProductId(),'qty'=>1]
                ];

                return $this->_helper->createOrder($orderData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically magento manage the order related information before placed order in **Quote**. So you need to create a quote programmatically and need to set **shipping and billing address, shipping method, payment method** etc. After that you can convert that  **quote** to order by calling **placeOrder($quoteId)**. 
For more information you can check [here](https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/).

Comment: With the reference of above mentioned link, I have written my code. Order is creating but, I have to create order automatically for the items in every customer's wishlist.

Comment: You mean when customer added product to wishlist?

Comment: When a new product is added, it should be added to the customer's wishlist. Then order should be automatically created for the products in the wishlist.

Comment: then you can use the the event product_save_after to generate the order after adding product to wish list.